# ANDROID passing variables between 2 methods

Tags: android

I have two methods in the same class ..

```
public static void first_method (int x,int y)
{
    int xx = x;
    int yy = y;
}


public void second_method (TextView tv)
{

}
```

How I can pass the variable xx from first method to second method ?

THANKS

Comment: not. both are local variables to the first_method. you can only pass their value(s) to the second method. after your edit: not at all. an int and a String are not even the same type.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
public static void first_method (int x,int y)
{
int xx = x;
int yy = y;
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("" + xx);
second_method(tv);
}

public void second_method (TextView tv )
{
     //do stuff with anyVar
}
```

Of course, a less simple way to do it would be to give the first method a return value.

```
public static int first_method (int x,int y)
{
int xx = x;
int yy = y;
return xx;
}

second_method(first_method(any_int, any_int2));
```

In this example the when you call `second_method`, it is called with the return value of `first_method(any_int, any_int2)`

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting you cannot make a reference to a none static method from within a static method.

Try:

```
public  void first_method (int x,int y)
{
int xx = x;
int yy = y;
second_method(xx);

}


public void second_method (int x)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the second method from the first method, then the code would be

```
public static void first_method (int x,int y)
{
    int xx = x;
    int yy = y;
    second_method(xx)
}

public void second_method (int xx)
{
        system.out.println(xx); // proof that xx was sent
}
```

However, if you're not going to call second_method from within first method, then just make xx a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global` variables if you don't want to set the `parameters` for called `function` `second_method()`

```
/*declare global variables*/
int global_x;  
int global_y;
public static void first_method (int x,int y)
{
    int xx = x;
    int yy = y;
    global_x = xx; /*assign value to global variable before function call*/
    global_y = yy;
    second_method (); /*values set in global variable, now call function*/
}


public void second_method ()
{
    /*Access the global variable here*/
    int temp_x = global_x;
    int temp_y = global_y;
}
```

Comment: considering the fact Java doesn't have global variables, you might want to re-phrase your answer.

Comment: well then in that case you can make use of constant file in android (ie; value.xml or string.xml) or sharedPreferences, Intent, Constant class data-members... There are lot more options but they are not good to be implemented in this case you explained in question.

Answer (score 0):

Response to (this version of) the question:

```
I have two methods in the same class ..

public static void first_method (int x,int y)
{
    int xx = x;
    int yy = y;
}


public void second_method (TextView tv)
{

}
How I can pass the variable xx from first method to second method ?

THANKS
```

Long story short: you can't. Both variables you have there, are local to the first_method. By using parameters, you can pass their value(s), but you will not be passing the variables themselves (big difference).

As for some answers already given, recommending the use of 'global variables': Java doesn't have global variables. They are referring to instance variables.

In this case, you would not be 'passing' them, but they would exist in a scope in which both methods can access them. When doing this, changing the value in one method, will effect the value in the other (which would not happen when passing the value as parameter and keeping the variable local).

Anyway, in order to pass them, you can't just pass an int and expect a method to receive an instance of TextView.